# How to monitor a filtering map process with a progressbar

Tags: qt, qml, qtlocation

I want to inform the user of the process of filtering points on a QML map by a progress bar. This process takes place in three phases:
filterAcceptsRow call rowCount and then call data. The values returned by data are compared with the filter and validate or not.

here is the filterAcceptsRow() :

```
bool NavaidsFilter::filterAcceptsRow(int sourceRow, const QModelIndex &sourceParent) const
{

    if(!m_boundaryZone.isValid()){
        return false;
    }
    QModelIndex ix = sourceModel()->index(sourceRow, 0, sourceParent);
    QGeoCoordinate pos = ix.data(NavaidsModel::PositionRole).value<QGeoCoordinate>();

    return m_boundaryZone.contains(pos);
}
```

Here is the rowCount() :

```
    Q_INVOKABLE int rowCount(const QModelIndex & parent = QModelIndex()) const{
    Q_UNUSED(parent)

    return mPoints.count();
}
```

And here is the data(), with a faulty QProgressDialog implemented :

```
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex & index, int role=Qt::DisplayRole) const {

    QProgressDialog filterDialog;
    filterDialog.setMinimum(0);
    filterDialog.setMaximum(mPoints.count());
    filterDialog.show();
    filterDialog.setValue(index.row());


    const NavaidsPoint &point = mPoints[index.row()];

    if (role == PositionRole){
        return QVariant::fromValue(point.position());}
    else if (role == OACICodeRole){
        return point.oaciCode();}
    else if (role == CountryCodeRole){
        return point.countryCode();}
    return QVariant();
}
```

Data seems to me the good part of the code in which we know the index of the current value via index.row() and the total of values via rowCount().

Knowing the progress by comparing the two numbers is obvious, but displaying it in a progress bar does not work as I coded it.

I tried to implement a QFutureWatcher to do this job, but unsuccessfully.

Do you have an idea about the solution to implement.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does it actually works? Is that your real code? each time data function is called new QProgressDialog will be created and destroyed right after data function is done. Is it QAbstractListModel? Why don't you use QSortFilterProxyModel for sorting?

Comment: Counting progress in `data()` function isn't a good idea as this function can be called by many other reasons than just filtering.

Comment: Yes but each time data is called it is a huge number of indexes which are reviewed (around 250k) it is why this process need to be monitored in progress. Where can I monitor the process in a better location ? @xplatforms the whole code runs, except QprogressDialog. But you're right, it is created and destroyed after data function is done, this is the pb. Of course NavaidsFilter derived from QSortFilterProxyModel for filtering.

Comment: @kontiki Do you want to see the amount of filtered items regarding all the items? or do you want to see the number of items compared to all? explain yourself better please, I think you have not given an adequate context so you currently have that kind of questions. The function data() is not suitable for it, it would be appropriate to use the QSortFilterProxyModel

Comment: The filtering process induced by QSortFilterProxyModel  check each point according to the criterias. So finally, I wish to display the rate of progression of the filtering process. Having 250000 items to filter with a current index to 5000, the filtering process is implemented at 2%. Then the amount of filtered items or the number of items vs all, from my point of view, is equal. These values are well known in the data(). An another way to get this will be fine. Maybe launching a signal in filterAcceptRows could be a solution to catch the number of items passed as I can know elsewhere the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to monitor the progress, you have to implement an [async worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952474/non-blocking-worker-interrupt-file-copy/32952945#32952945). It has to complete one step, pause, notify the GUI, give it time to reflect the change, and only then do the next step, and so until finished.

If you do it in a tight loop, this will absolutely massacre your performance, so you have to take care that it is not too finely grained. Something like a progress bar should not get more than 10 updates a second.

The reason it doesn't work for you is that the tread is blocked while the work is being done, so the progress bar cannot update until it all the work is finished.