# Qt: Call a function with arguments periodically

Tags: c++, qt

**Problem**: 
I have a function `void myFunc(data)`

I am reading data from database using QSqlQuery:

```
QSqlQuery qry;
if (qry.exec("SELECT data, interval from table"))
{
   while(qry.next())
   {
       // Somehow create and call function: myFunc(int data) periodically with interval = interval
   }
}
```

As far as I understand I could use a timer like that:

```
QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(myFunc()));
timer->start(interval); //time specified in ms
```

but how can I pass argument `data` to `myFunc` when I create this timer?

Comment: You might store information into `this` if acceptable.

Comment: Can you get your `int` data in the `myFunc()` slot and then have that slot call your `myFunc(int data)` function?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32952474/non-blocking-worker-interrupt-file-copy/32952945#32952945

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use C++11, you can connect your timer to a lambda function in which you capture your data value.

Example (untested):

```
int interval = 500;
int data = 42;

QTimer *timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, [data] {
    /* Implement your logic here */
});
```

Answer (score 2):

One more option: have a QObject-derived class that runs the function calling  `QObject::startTimer`. In this same class, use a `QMap<int, int>` where each pair has the timer id as key and the data as value.

A simple implementation:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QMap>

class TimedExecution : QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    TimedExecution() : QObject(0){}
    void addFunction(int data, int interval);
protected:
    void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event);
private:
    QMap<int, int> map;
};
```

Use the `addFunction` method to create a new timed execution task (the passed interval is assumed to be expressed in seconds, here):

```
void TimedExecution::addFunction(int data, int interval)
{
    map.insert(startTimer(interval * 1000), data);
}
```

Start the same function in the overridden `timerEvent` method, passing the data retrieved from the map, using the timer id retrieved from the timer event as the map key:

```
void TimedExecution::timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event)
{
    myFunc( map[event->timerId()] );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can use Qt5 and C++11 then you can leverage `std::bind`:

for example, assuming `decltype(this)==MyClass*`:

```
connect(timer, &QTimer::timeout, this, std::bind(&MyClass::myFunc,this,data));
```

Answer (score 1):

You have lots of options:

- As mentioned in comments store the int data in `this`, maybe in a `std::map<QTimer*, int>` so that when you have multiple timers you can lookup the correct value and call `myFunc` with it. Since you have not stated if `myFunc` is one function or there can be multiple, you may have to store the function as well
- You can make a class which gets the `data` value in the constructor, saves it in a member, you connect a slot of that class to the timer, and from the slot invoke `myFunc()` with the stored value
- You can make a class that inherits from `QTimer` and has the data you need, use that class when creating the timer instead of the plain `QTimer`, and then in the slot `myFunc` you can access that instance via `QObject::sender()`, cast it to your type and do whatever needs to be done.